# How to configure a Keycloak trustore in Keycloak Docker image/Kubernetes

Tags: keycloak

I build my own Keycloak Docker image based on the jboss/keycloak Docker image version 12.0.4. The custom image includes themes and a few custom plugins. This Docker image is deployed to a Kubernetes cluster using a Helm chart. I'm testing out a brokered IdP configuration against Auth0 and I'm almost there. The last thing I need is to configure a truststore with Auth0's cert.

I'm thinking the best way to do this would be to include the trust store when I build my Docker image, but I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Note: upgrading to later version of Keycloak is not an option at this time.

Comment: The certificates that you want to add to the truststore are they k8s secrets?

Comment: No. Are you suggesting that one way to handle this would be to put the cert in a secret, mount that secret as a file and then add it to the truststore on startup? I didn't think of that. I guess another way would be to just put the truststore file in a secret and mount that.

Comment: yep, it also depends on your k8s setup; If you also deploy some kind of certificate provider like cert-manager that you would mount the tls secrets into the kc pod

Answer (score 0):

What I finally came up with:

**Update**: See comments by @dreamcrash. Mounting file from a secret is the better way to go.

Once I figured out how to get the appropriate cert from Auth0 (the InstallCert utility was a great help https://github.com/escline/InstallCert), I created a trust store using the Java keytool utility containing that cert. I added the resulting .jks file to my Docker image at build time.  I then had to tell Keycloak about it by adding a JBoss CLI script like so:

```
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/:add
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/provider=file/:add(enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/provider=file/:map-put(name=properties,key=file,value=/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keycloak.jks)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/provider=file/:map-put(name=properties,key=password,value=changeit)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/provider=file/:map-put(name=properties,key=hostname-verification-policy,value=ANY)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=truststore/provider=file/:map-put(name=properties,key=disabled,value=false)
```

The Helm chart that I use has provisions for defining these types of scripts that run during Keycloak startup.

Note that this was the procedure for Keycloak 12.0.4. This has changed quite a bit in more recent versions of Keycloak.